# Simple python region growing image segmentation tool?

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I was wondering if there was a simple python toolkit for region-based image segmentation. I have a grayscale image, and my goal is to efficiently find a complete segmentation such that the pixel values in each region are similar (presumably the definition of "similar" will be determined by some tolerance parameter). I am looking for an instance segmentation where every pixel belongs exactly one region.

I have looked at the scikit-image segmentation module (https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html), but the tools there didn't seem to do what I was looking for. For instance, skimage.segmentation.watershed looked attractive, but gave poor results using markers=None.

Answer (score 1):

The [flood fill](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html#flood-fill) algorithm from scikit-image seems close to what you want, has a tolerance parameter as well.

For more fine-tuned control you can check out [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/dbd/tutorial_distance_transform.html)